# Unable to fetch all bold <em> tags from google search result

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So im using this code to fetch :-

- All the bold / tags from google search result
- All the text inside
  each of the search result links

But am unable to fetch them all. Its failing on some of the tags as well as the entire text which doesnt make sense as Im pulling all the content of a tag.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36'}


from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
link=("https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN789IN790&ei=P4b9Wp4MxPP1A67gk-gI&q=%28%27United+States%27%2C+%27US+DOL+OASAM+-+OCIO%27%2C+%27200+CONSTITUTION+AVE+NW%27%29&oq=%28%27United+States%27%2C+%27US+DOL+OASAM+-+OCIO%27%2C+%27200+CONSTITUTION+AVE+NW%27%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3...44692.45689.0.46041.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DqJsrKbp_Js")
browser.get(link)
s=requests.get(browser.current_url, headers=headers)
soup =BeautifulSoup(s.content,'html.parser')


for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "s"}):
    for k in i.findAll("span",{"class":"st"}):
        print (k.text)
```

Required SAMPLE OUTPUT:

> OASAM Contacts. OASAM National and Regional Office Information. National >Office: Main Office. Office of the Assistant Secretary for Administration and >Management U.S. Department of Labor 200 Constitution Avenue, N.W.. Suite S->2203. Washington, DC 20210. Phone: (202) 693-4040. Fax: (202) 693-4055. Business ...

The above code fails to pull out all the text as is visible in the browser & is printing only partial text.

===========================================================================

Similarly when trying to pull out all the bold text from search result, Im not getting all the bold texts. A lot of them are not getting fetched even though they lie in the same vicinity as defined by tag

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("st"):
    for k in (i.find_elements_by_tag_name("em")):
        print (k.text)
    print ("=====")
```

For first link it should have printed (Required SAMPLE OUTPUT):-

> OASAM
>
> OASAM
>
> of the
>
> U.S. Department of Labor 200 Constitution Avenue, N.W.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath for selecting all bold texts.

```
.//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/h3/a
```

and for all texts inside

```
 .//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/span
```